# What does the Unix Philosophy say that a tool should do with data that ends with a sequence of characters and no newline?

Tags: unix

It is my understanding that Unix defines a "line" as a sequence of zero of more characters followed by a newline. Do I understand correctly?

The last line is a "line" (of course) so the last line must have a newline. Is that correct?

Suppose there is a sequence of characters, a newline, and then a sequence of characters. That is, no newline after the last sequence of characters. What does that mean? Does it mean that it is bad/invalid data? What does the Unix Philosophy say that a tool should do with such data? Reject it? Process all lines and ignore the last sequence of characters? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a handful of examples from Linux:

```
$ printf 'line\neof' > y
$ cat y
line
eof$ 
$ wc -l y
1 y
$ grep eof y
eof
$ tac y
eofline
$ rev y
enil
foe$ sort y
eof
line
$ tail -n 1 y
eof$ sed -n 1p y
line
$ sed -n 2p y
eof$
```

As you can see, the behavior isn't consistent:

- `cat` and `wc` are very literal and don't add any missing newline
- `grep` and `sort` add a newline
- `rev`, `sed` and `tail` consider the last line but don't add a newline
- `tac` just gets confused

But you'll also note:

- None of those programs treat it as invalid data.
- None of these programs ignore the part after the last newline.
- For the most part, these programs will work as the user would expect them to work if piped together.

So if there's any "Unix philosophy" takeaway here, it's less about newlines and more about input handling as noted above.

Comment: Linux isn't Unix and does not always follow the Unix Philosophy.

Comment: None of them are Unix, and those are GNU utilities, not Linux-specific. FWIW I tried the native utilities from MacOS and the only difference was `rev`.

Comment: @root : no `tac` wasn't "confused" at all - it did exactly what it oughtta do cuz it's only job is to print in reverse order instead of trying to make any sense out of what it's being asked to print at all.

Comment: @Rob : does Linux still have a "philosophy" these days, or they pretty much went for trying to be all things to all people ?

Comment: `tac` does have to make sense of what it's being asked to print, it doesn't just print in reverse byte by byte, and not even line by line, it specifically removes the separator from the stream and instead prints it at the end of each part (line), so I'd expect it to use the separator to separate the two lines (i.e. print the separator after the first part printed).

Answer (score 2):

Answering the questions in your question one at a time:

1. It is my understanding that Unix defines a "line" as a sequence of
   zero of more characters followed by a newline. Do I understand correctly?

Yes, though it's not exactly a Unix definition it's a POSIX one, but most if not all Unix boxes these days are POSIX compliant. What you're referring to is the POSIX definition of a line:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206

> 3.206 Line
>
> A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a
> terminating  character.

2. The last line is a "line" (of course) so the last line must have a newline. Is that correct?

Yes. POSIX further defines a text file as a series of such lines:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403

> 3.403 Text File
>
> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The
> lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed {LINE_MAX}
> bytes in length, including the <newline> character. Although
> POSIX.1-2017 does not distinguish between text files and binary files
> (see the ISO C standard), many utilities only produce predictable or
> meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities
> that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN
> or INPUT FILES sections.

3. Suppose there is a sequence of characters, a newline, and then a sequence of characters. That is, no newline after the last sequence of characters. What does that mean?

That means it's a file but not a POSIX text file and so what any given text-processing tool does with it is undefined behavior, at the whim of the developers of every variant of that tool to treat however they see fit.

4. Does it mean that it is bad/invalid data?

No, it's just not a text file.

5. What does the Unix Philosophy say that a tool should do with such data? Reject it? Process all lines and ignore the last sequence of characters? Something else?

It depends on the tool. If it's a text processing tool then read the man page for that tool to find out what it does with input that is not a valid text file since it's behavior is not defined by POSIX. If it's not a text processing tool then read the POSIX standard or the man page as it's behavior should be defined in one or both locations.

The missing question is - how do we know it's a text processing tool or not?

The answer to that is to read the POSIX spec and look for the section that says "STDIN" or "INPUT FILES". There it will say the input is a text file for text processing tools, or a file for others. For example (emphasis mine):

awk: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

> Input files to the awk program from any of the following sources shall be **text files**

sed: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

> The input files shall be **text files**

grep: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

> The input files shall be **text files**

read: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

> The standard input shall be a **text file**

Whereas:

wc: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wc.html

> The input files may be of **any type**

cat: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html

> The input files can be **any file type**

and note that `tail` depends on the arguments used:

tail: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html

> If the -c option is specified, the input file can contain **arbitrary
> data**; otherwise, the input file shall be a **text file**.

In many cases text processing tools will accept input that is not a text file and try to do something sensible with it but I personally won't rely on it as you can get surprises. For example, using GNU `awk` and the `read` built into GNU `bash` 4.4.12, here are 2 scripts you might reasonably expect to be equivalent and they do behave so with a valid text file as input:

```
$ printf 'line 1\nline 2\n' > file

$ awk '{print $0}' < file
line 1
line 2

$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file
line 1
line 2
```

but now try it with input that is not a valid text file:

```
$ printf 'line 1\nline 2' > file

$ awk '{print $0}' < file
line 1
line 2

$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file
line 1
$
```

Note the missing `line 2` from the `read` loop output.

So, do NOT run text-processing tools on input that isn't a valid text file without checking the man page for the specific version of the tool you are going to use to find out how it is designed to behave given that input.

When faced with a file and you don't know if it has a terminating newline or not, you could always add one by using tools that can run on files that are not text files, e.g.:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < \
    <(cat file; [[ -n "$(tail -c1 file)" ]] && echo)
line 1
line 2
```